# Replace a single pole with programmable switch

Tags: electrical, light, smart-switch

Sorry for the repost, but the former q/a’s didn’t answer my particular question. I have a programmable switch, to replace a single pole switch at a three gang switch plate (the one on the right, in the photo.)

Where does the neutral go?  What am I looking at?

[image: switches]

Comment: Neutral will be connected to neutrals(white) that comes with the black wires for that switch.  It seem all the neutrals are connected together so no guessing.  A picture showing the white wires better will help, but it seems like they are connected together.

Comment: Normally the neutral (white) would go to the other neutrals in the box and the 2 blacks simply replace the blacks on the switch you are replacing.  I can't see how the neutrals are connected from your pic.  An important question is what does the switch on the left do (with the red tape on it)??  Is it a 3-way, if so, we need to be careful about making sure what is a true neutral and what are travelers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a neutral *that is associated with a hot wire going to the switch*.

Look at the 2 hot wires going to the switch you want to replace.

Follow each hot back to the cable where they enter the box. If one goes off into a pigtailed mess, follow the other hot. That cable may have a neutral wire (not always). If you find one, you're in luck.  Follow that neutral wire to a splice point such as a wire nut. Add your neutral to those - keep them together and add yours also.

Use good splicing technique, always. Failure to do so can result in arc faults which can start fires, or at least, be a major nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few white wires tied together under a red wire nut tucked in the back of the box. That's where the neutral for your new switch goes. It looks like the bottom wire on your old switch is the feed so that will go to the line side of your new switch. The other wire will go to the load side.

Comment: Just laughing at the DV.